# Connecting to board through ssh failed - reformat SD card

Tags: linux, ssh, embedded, sd-card

I am trying to connect to a FOX G20 V board through ssh by typing `ssh dico@foxboard`. However, there is a problem with the connection because the SD card is corrupt so I am not able to connect to the board (as specified by the [manual](http://www.acmesystems.it/foxg20_getting_started)). Therefore, I need to format my SD card, i.e, erase everything in it. I don't have an SD card adapater so I can't insert the card into my Linux machine. And since I can't connect to the board, I'm wondering how I can erase the SD card memory (through terminal perhaps?). I would appreciate any advice/help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not because the card is corrupted you cannot access it; rather the card is corrupted, so the board won't boot so there is no OS to connect to or mount the card.  It's a chicken-egg situation.  The board boots from the SD card; even if you erased the card, you'd have nothing to boot and still would not be able to access the card!  Erasing the card is not the solution to your problem; that would leave you no further forward than the corrupted card (if it is truly corrupted and not just blank!)

You will need to re-image the card or get a replacement card. An inexpensive card adapter will probably be simpler and lower cost, and you'll need it in the long run.  The on-chip bootstrap probably has only minimal capability to load and run secondary bootstrap code from the card, it cannot perform card management such as formatting.

You can purchase replacement pre-loaded cards [here](http://www.acmesystems.it/catalog_sdcard) and instructions for loading your own from Linux are [here](http://www.acmesystems.it/binary_repository).  You can get a [simple card reader](http://www.digitalmediastore.co.uk/memory_cards/card_reader/writers/Integral_Single_Slot_SD__SDHC__SDXC_USB_20_Card_Reader__INT-SDREADER-D) for less than the price of these cards however.

Comment: How can I reimage the card? Is there a solution to this problem without having to spend any money?

Comment: @JohnSmith, As per the link in the answer. You can do it without spending money if you can find, beg, steal or borrow a PC or laptop with a memory card reader, (or borrow a card reader of course). If you only have a Windows PC, use a Linux virtual machine on it.  How much money is too much - if we are quibbling about the (very low) cost of a card reader; you are probably in the wrong game.  For what you are doing, I would say that it is essential development equipment.

Comment: When you have a card working, I would take a image of it to make re-imaging simpler - you can do that in Windows using [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) if that is more readily available to you than Linux.

Comment: I now have a card reader and I am working on two machines actually. I have both a Linux machine and a windows machine at my disposal. Can you therefore tell me one more time what to do please to fix my situation? Thanks again

Comment: @JohnSmith : I don't think I can make it any clearer than the board manufacturers own instructions already mentioned in the answer: http://www.acmesystems.it/binary_repository. I am not an expert on this particular board, just applying general expertise and Googling for you!

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully when I follow these steps the board will start working again.

Comment: I'm now trying to create the partition tables as suggested by the link, but I'm using the terminal (since I can't download gparted). But when I create the partition tables as they specify in the tuturial, I get an error when I remove the microSD card and plug it back in: `Unable to mount 32MB Filesystem`. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: I don't know - you have to format the partitions too perhaps?  I'm no Linux expert and we are now way off topic for StackOverflow.  In fact the question was off topic in the first place, and this is not what the comments are for.  You should contact the vendor http://www.acmesystems.it/questions

Comment: Thank you for your help as usual! I appreciate your time!